# Continuous audio recorder for Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am looking for an Android application that records the sound all the time and stores it for a few days. What I want exactly :

- Always record the sound (as soon as the phone is on or I launch the app until the phone is off)
- Store the sound in log files by pieces (e.g. of 1 hour)
- Delete the files after some time (e.g. 3 days)
- No format preference
- Storage limit : no more than 2GB par day (which is possible in MP3 according to [this website](http://www.audiomountain.com/tech/audio-file-size.html))
- No real quality limit

I don't want to spy anyone, it is for personnal use only. I want to be able to listen something again if it was important, funny, unclear...
I don't want a dedicated device because I think I would be easier to manage the audio files on my phone (save and listen the ones I want, delete the others)

Comment: What do you mean by record the sound 'permanently', when you want it to automatically delete it after a period of time?

Comment: @user151841 I mean that the audio is recorded all the time

Comment: You might want to change that to 'continuous' or 'always-on'

Comment: You might need additional criteria here: desired sound format and quality, plus available storage. Doing continuous recording (I disagree with @user151841 here: other than "continuous recording", "always-on" doesn't necessarily mean "non-stop recording") can be very space consuming. So you might consider an app that actually only records if there is some "noise" to record – and stops recording when it's "dead silent". One more criterion: is there any price limit? Also, be welcome to my list of apps for [Audio Recording](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_audiorec).

Comment: Couple of quick notes:  1) you'll have to have the phone "on", not sleeping, for that whole period, so you'll probably want it plugged in.  And 2) This is doable (e.g., the uncompressed file usage for the lowest quality of sound (16 bit 44.1 KHz) is around 7.6 Gigabytes per day), but you'll want compression too.    Personally, I have to ask: why don't you just buy a dedicated eavesdropping (sorry, surveillance) device?

Comment: For example, this is only $249, and will more than double your needs. Plus you don't have to use your cell phone to do it:   http://www.cheatersspyshop.com/long-duration-voice-recorder-16gb-wireless-mic.html

Comment: @CPerkins while I generally agree (+1), some of your values are wrong: min sampling rate is ~8kHz (speech), and you could also use 8bit ([source](http://www.audio-issues.com/home-recording-studio/demystifying-audio-formats-what-format-should-you-record-in/)), and set it to Mono. Using the [file size calculator](http://www.theaudioarchive.com/TAA_Resources_File_Size.htm), this results in ~28MB/h or ~675MB/d uncompressed (the compressed size makes no sense on that calculator). Better [raw numbers here](http://www.audiomountain.com/tech/audio-file-size.html): MP3 starts at ~90MB/day.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the correction.  Guess my source was wrong.   I still think a dedicated eavesdropping device is better, unless the goal here is to plant a phone-bug on an unsuspecting person, like a spouse: in that case, the dedicated device wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: @CPerkins No I don't want to spy anyone, it's just for personnal use. I want to be able to listen something again if it was important, funny... I don't want a dedicated device because I think I would be easier to manage the audio files on my phone (save and listen the ones I want, delete the others).

Comment: So this isn't for spying, it's for recording people without their knowledge or consent.  I understand now.   You'll still have power issues since you'll need to prevent your phone from sleeping, though you could put it in airplane mode to conserve battery.

Comment: @CPerkins Leaving politics out (mentioning the implications is of course good! Like to let people know you're recording), there are legal and legit uses for this. Imagine you "hear things" and everyone's claiming you're just imagining it, this gives you a change for an "independent source". A baby monitor (heh! power-source attached! :) or security-surveillance of your home (again with power attached – and here a 24/7 absolutely makes sense) are other options. Plus many more. So shall we concentrate on the "solution" now? :D